# Radio buttons not retaining selection when user controls are posted back

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, partial-page-refresh

I  am facing some problems when page is posted back partially. I have some radio buttons based on which I am making tr display="" and display="none" by javascript. After that  I am adding rows gridview. The gridview contains empltyTemplate and footer to add new rows. But when I add row in grid view, the user control is posted back and hence all the tr becomes displa="none" which is default when page is loaded. I tried to keep gridview in update panel but it not working. Hierarchy of my controls is as below.

Level-1-Master page--->Level-2-master page--->Level 3-.aspx page--->Level 4-user control--->Level-5 -multiple accordians-->Level-6: 1 user control in each accordian..

code is too long to past here.. I tried to keep update panel inside user control(Level 6) but it was not working. After some googling I found that update pane not works if it is inside accrdian. So I tried to keep all accrdian inside update panel but in that case .aspx page is not posted back but all user controls placed inside accrodian are posted back so the selection is set as they are on default load.

I want all selection to retain when the last level user control is posted back.

The situation is quite complex to understand but this is what the things are..How to solve my problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changes made to the DOM from JavaScript are not retained cross-PostBack; the server has no idea what you've done, and therefore has no way to track it.

To solve this, you either need to have your JS code update state on the server side with a Callback or Ajax call -- or perhaps have it update a hidden input field in the form that reflects the state of your  tags, and have the server look there and update the rendered HTML accordingly.